# How do I save a soldier in the Nick of Time?

Tags: achievements, xcom-2

The achievement "Nick of Time" has the following description:

> Evacuate a soldier whose bleed-out timer is still running

I had it occur to me once, and saved this soldier by killing all hostiles and completing the objective. The achievement did not unlock however. What is the specific trigger for this achievement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to evac a bleeding-out soldier by calling in the Skyranger and using the "Evac" ability whilst the soldier carrying them is in the landing zone.